# What's the nearest star that could go Supernova in the near future?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars, supernova, milky-way

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IK_Pegasi B is the nearest supernova candidate, but that white dwarf that's part of the system won't go supernova for around 2 billion years.
What's the nearest star that could plausibly go Supernova in the next 100,000 years or so.
Or in other words, what's the nearest star where it going supernova wouldn't confuse the hell out of astronomers.

Comment: Why would any near-earth supernova confuse the hell out of astronomers?

Comment: If it were a main sequence star it would, or if it weighed only a few solar masses.

Answer (score 4):

[Betelgeuse, Betelgeuse, Betelgeuse](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.00287.pdf)